# mpi_alltoall on nonequal number of grids and processes

Tags: mpi

I understand the general usage of MPI_alltoall, which can be described by the following figure[image]

But in practice, it is almost not always that the number of processes will equal to the number grids. The above case assume process = grid = 4. If numbers are not equal, I will have rectangular grids. Below I show an example showing a similar alltoall operation, but nonequal number of grids and processes (grid = 8, process = 2). [image]

My question is then very straightforward, how should I achieve that?
I have looked over alltoallv, but I don't think it will work.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a "natural" alltoall would be

```
MPI_Alltoall(sbuf, 4, MPI_INT, rbuf, 4, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and you would end up with

```
P0 = { A0, A1, A2, A3, C0, C1, C2, C3}
P1 = { B0, B1, B2, B3, D0, D1, D2, D3}
```

your case is a bit convoluted and you have to use (complex) derived datatypes. (note I did not free the intermediate datatypes in order to keep the code readable)

```
    MPI_Datatype tmp, stype, rtype;

    /* derived datatype for send */
    MPI_Type_vector(2, 1, 4, MPI_INT, &tmp); /* {0, 4} */
    MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp, 0, 4, &tmp); /* next type starts at 1 */
    MPI_Type_contiguous(2, tmp, &tmp); /* {0, 4, 1, 5} */
    MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp, 0, 8, &stype); /* next type starts at 2, likely unnecessary */
    MPI_Type_commit(&stype);

    /* derived datatype for recv */
    MPI_Type_vector(2, 2, 4, MPI_INT, &tmp); /* {0, 1, 4, 5 } */
    MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp, 0, 8, &rtype); /* next type starts at 2 */
    MPI_Type_commit(&rtype);

    /* all2all */
    /* thanks to the derived datatypes :
       P0 sends {A0, B0, A1, B1} to P0 and {A2, B2, A3, B3} to P1
       P0 receives {A0, B0, .., .., A1, B1, .., ..} from itself, and
       { .., .., C0, D0, .., .., C1, D1} from P1 } */
    MPI_Alltoall(sbuf, 1, stype, rbuf, 1, rtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: The second resize for the send type is redundant.

Comment: thanks for sharing the code. I have tested it, and it works. Do you mind to explain more on the logic of creating those new datatypes? I am a newbie in using MPI

Comment: @jchan192 I added some comments about the datatypes usage.

Comment: @HristoIliev thanks, I never know if the last resize is mandated by the standard or is taken for granted since this is how major MPI libraries were implemented ...

Comment: Acording to the standard, a contiguous type created from `count` elements of old type with extent `ext` has an extent of `count * ext`. See Example 4.9 in Section 4.1.6 "Lower-Bound and Upper-Bound Markers" (page 105). So the second resize is redundant.

Comment: @jchan192 you need a strided vector type in order to build a block out of A0 and B0. This type spans 5 elements and if MPI goes for another block, it will start from B1 and then access something past the buffer. This is not what you want. Instead, you want the second block to start at A1. To achieve that, `MPI_Type_create_resized` changes the "extent" of the vector type, forcing MPI to treat it as a type of size one element. This way, the second block in a contiguous type with two repetitions of the resized type will start from A1 and the type will appear to be of size two elements.

Comment: @jchan192 so when all-to-all starts building chunks to send around, the first chunk will start at A0 and will contain A0 B0 A1 B1. The second chunk will start at two elements past A0, i.e. A2, and will contain A2 B2 A3 B3. A similar trick is used on the receiver side.

Comment: @jchan192 You first create a strided type that turns A0 B0 A1 B1 into A0 B0 x x A1 B1. You cannot use this type directly in all-to-all since the next chunk will start after B1 and you'll get A0 B0 x x A1 B1 C0 D0 x x C1 D1. So again, you resize the type to be of size two elements and now MPI will place the second chunk after B0 and you get A0 B0 C0 D0 A1 B1 C1 D1.

Comment: @HristoIliev If the prupose of using 'MPI_Type_create_resized' is to force MPI to start from A1 again, why are the input 0 and 4? As I understand, they are the lowerbound, and extent. Isnt the extend simply 1? since Its just beside the first block A0.

Comment: Extent is in bytes

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ah ok. Thank you. I learned a lot from you and HristoIliev

Comment: @jchan192 both LB and extent are in bytes